# Como eu salvo dados em um arquivo JSON usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Gostaria de pegar a saída do console.log e ficar salvando em um arquivo .JSON e depois obter uma busca dentro dele mesmo

Comment: NodeJS ou browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Comment: Através do Browser mas vi aqui algumas coisas sobre segurança que praticamente me deixou ciente que não seria possível